# How to log from multiple ec2 instances(load balanced) to a common server using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to log from multiple ec2 instances(load balanced) to a common server using AWS.

I have multiple images of ec2 instance with apache servers . I want to log all the log data to a common server.

Do AWS provide any tools for doing this.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html

Answer (score 1):

AWS Cloud Watch has this feature where you can add multiple server logs and monitor them through Cloud Watch console. See below steps

http://cloudacademy.com/blog/centralized-log-management-with-aws-cloudwatch-part-1-of-3/